# Выровнять блок вертикально относительно изображения без использования flex'а

Tags: html, css

Есть два блока с `float: left`. Один из них - картинка, внутри другого -
 произвольное кол-во текста.

Как выровнять второй блок посередине по-вертикали относительно первого, не прибегая к использованию `flex-box`?

```css
   .wrapper:after,.wrapper:before{
          content: '';
          display: table;
          clear: both;
    }
    .text, .img{
       float: left;
    }
    .img{
       width: 30%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .text{
       width: 70%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       padding-left: 30px;
    }
    a{
       display: block;
       margin-top: 20px;
       height: 40px;
       line-height: 40px;
       background-color: #0094de;
       text-align: center;
       width: 130px;
       color: #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
       border-radius: 26px
    }
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
       <img src="http://forums.ferra.ru/uploads/profile/photo-106401.png" class="img">
       <div class="text">
          <span>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</span>
          <a href="">Подробнее</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Предоствьте код, не совсем понятно.

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C помощью  `vertical-align: middle;`:

```css
.wrapper:after,
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.text,
.img {
  /* float: left; это убираем*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img {
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  width: 69%;/*тут чуть по меньше*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #0094de;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 26px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://forums.ferra.ru/uploads/profile/photo-106401.png" class="img">
  <div class="text">
    <span>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</span>
    <a href="">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но можете объяснить пару моментов: почему width: 69% а не 70% и примерную логику. Т.е. img создаёт строку высотой с себя, относительно которой блок, обтекающий её, становится по центру, хотя ему не задан vertical-align. И что будет в случае, если блок по высоте выйдет больше, чем высота картинки?

Comment: @Kellok Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: `69%` потому-что это инлайн-блок, он ведет себя как текст. В тексте есть пробелы, они создают дополнительную ширину. В теории их можно убрать `font-size:0`, тогда можно оставить `70%`, но это усложнение не имеет отношения к вопросу

Comment: _И что будет в случае, если блок по высоте выйдет больше, чем высота картинки?_ соответственно картинка встанет по центру